# Svg to the canvas ,fill color does not work

Tags: canvas, svg, blob, fill, drawimage

http://codepen.io/w12594822/pen/xgjomO

```
var svgText = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctxt = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

function drawInlineSVG(ctx, rawSVG, callback) {

var svg = new Blob([rawSVG], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),
    domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
    url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg),
    img = new Image;

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);     
    domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    callback(this);
};

img.src = url;
}  
drawInlineSVG(ctxt, svgText, function() {});
```

I would like to svg drawn to the canvas, chrome 52 can, Firefox can, but chrome54 + can not

Comment: You've done the [right thing here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=688671). What do expect that a question here will achieve?